# Append icon as variable or HTML binding in controller

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, font-awesome

Using Angular and JQuery, I am trying to append a FontAwesome icon to a `div`.

Here is my TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  faCoffee = faCoffee;
  faLifeRing = faLifeRing;

  ngOnInit() {
    $("div").append(this.faCoffee); //Does not work
    $("div").append("<fa-icon [icon]='faCoffee'></fa-icon>"); //Does not work

    //Works
    $("div").append("<fa-icon _ngcontent-c7='' class='ng-fa-icon' ng-reflect-icon-prop='[object Object]'><svg aria-hidden='true' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='coffee' class='svg-inline--fa fa-coffee fa-w-20' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 640 512'><path fill='currentColor' d='M192 384h192c53 0 96-43 96-96h32c70.6 0 128-57.4 128-128S582.6 32 512 32H120c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24v232c0 53 43 96 96 96zM512 96c35.3 0 64 28.7 64 64s-28.7 64-64 64h-32V96h32zm47.7 384H48.3c-47.6 0-61-64-36-64h583.3c25 0 11.8 64-35.9 64z'></path></svg></fa-icon>")

  }

}
```

Ideally, I'd like to append `<fa-icon [icon]='faCoffee'></fa-icon>` as that is what I can use in the HTML with its binding.

Is there an easy way I can do this without appending the entire HTML of the icon?

**Edit:** I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvgkyk).

Comment: can you just put that html in the template instead of the .ts file?

Comment: @JBoothUA For this solution, I actually cannot as the I am appending to a DOM element outside of my Angular app.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think the problem here is using Angular binding outside of the Angular app.

```
[icon]='faCoffee'
```

implies that faCoffee is a variable, you MIGHT be able to get away with it without the variable.  replace the [icon] binding with;

```
icon='actual value not a variable'
```

but most likely in order to run an Angular Component outside of an Angular app you would have to convert it to an Angular Element.

Or you could use the Angular CDK's DomPortalHost.

The portal host can add angular elements to the page dynamically and using the DomPortalHost you should be able to target an area outside of the Angular app.
Something like this:

```
    // Locate an element that exists on the page
    const headerElement = document.querySelector('#pageHeader');
    // Locate the component factory for the HeaderComponent
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HeaderComponent);
    // Generate an instance of the HeaderComponent 
    this.componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], headerElement);
    // Attach to the component to Angular's component tree for dirty checking
    this.applicationRef.attachView(this.componentRef.hostView);
```